# Cant install program using apt-get like virtualbox or cmake

Tags: apt

I am using kubuntu 14.04 lts running on intel core i3,and has amd 6000m radion gpu

When I am going to install `cmake` or `virtual box` using terminal I always get this:error

```
sudo apt-get install cmake
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  cmake-data gcc gcc-4.8 libasan0 libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev
  libgcc-4.8-dev libitm1 libtsan0 linux-libc-dev manpages-dev
Suggested packages:
  codeblocks eclipse gcc-multilib autoconf automake1.9 libtool flex bison gcc-doc
  gcc-4.8-multilib gcc-4.8-doc gcc-4.8-locales libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg
  libitm1-dbg libatomic1-dbg libasan0-dbg libtsan0-dbg libbacktrace1-dbg
  libquadmath0-dbg glibc-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cmake cmake-data gcc gcc-4.8 libasan0 libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev
  libgcc-4.8-dev libitm1 libtsan0 linux-libc-dev manpages-dev
0 upgraded, 13 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,618 kB/14.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 57.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Media change: please insert the disc labeled
 'Kubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140416.1)'
in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press enter
```

I've searched lot on google but cant get satisfactory answer.

I am expecting answer to solve this problem.

Comment: @DuminduMahawela Thanks Mate...and thanks for reformatting my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to get an effective answer it would be very helpful to know the following about the computer you're talking about:

1. is it connected to the Internet? Try `curl www.google.com` in a terminal emulator and see if you get some HTML in your terminal.
2. Start a terminal emulator (do it by pressing `Ctrl + Alt + t`). Type
   `awk '!/^#/ {print;}' /etc/apt/sources.list` and hit the enter key. Edit your question above and add the output of the command you've just run.

Comment: Upvote my answerr...or voodoo will get you : p

Comment: i m new to askubuntu,and i dont have enough rep to upvote ur ans.sorry...but i m thankful for your help